# Stop fgets after 5 seconds in C

Tags: c, fgets

Hi I am making a program that prompts the user using fgets such as.

```
char* option = malloc(64);
fgets(option, 60, stdin);
```

I'm looking for a way to stop this fgets and print something out if the user takes to long to input a command.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

use

```
fflush(stdin);
gets(option);
```

it will work :)